# Kafka Service going down automatically

Tags: java, apache-kafka, debezium

Currently I am using kafka_2.12-2.5.0 with Java Service (Spring-boot).
I used to start zookeeper kafka and then debezium services first and they used to run successfully.
After that If I try to run java service then kafka service is going down within some time
At That Time Debezium Showing these logs continuously :

```
[2020-10-09 06:45:58,503] WARN [Producer clientId=connector-producer-sql-server-connection-0] Connection to node 0 (vsi-kafka-dev-01.c.presence-ss.internal/10.128.15.238:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:762)
```

And At the same time Java service showing these logs continuously :

```
[2020-10-09 11:11:39.635 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#9-0-C-1] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=vsiconsumers] Connection to node 0 (vsi-kafka-dev-01.c.presence-ss.internal/10.128.15.238:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I have used default properties in sh files just changed DB and IP related changes.

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "kafka service is going down"? Are the Kafka brokers actually shutting down? Or not accepting connections? Or some other fault? Do you have any logs from the Kafka or ZK processes that would help to understand the problem?

Comment: when you run the application check heap memory . if it is not enough may be kafka get down